# Very weird flickering on desktop

Tags: drivers, gnome, graphics, amd-graphics, flicker

Shortly after installing Ubuntu 18.04 in my computer I noticed that very frequently and without any apparent reason the desktop and specially Google Chrome windows (although not exclusively) **start flickering**, like **momentarily showing windows that are behind it**.

I recorded a [short video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x6Mv2Obwh5qx9_ZoAeW-S9ktQXg_Z1RK/view?usp=sharing) from my phone showing the screen.

You might notice that GNOME is very heavily themed, but the error started happening before they were installed (I've been trying to find the problem for a while now). I even changed kernels afterwards, without any change (I had to patch-in compatibility for my touchscreen).

This is an HP Envy X360, running at full 1080p. I suspect it might be related to the AMD drivers (native *Radeon R7*).

Any **ideas for debugging or any fix**? I can't even describe the glitch properly so I haven't had any good luck with Google.

EDIT: I changed the screencast for a video from my phone since most of the flickering dissapears instantly when any recording is started.

Comment: I would try a different kernel version. What does `uname -r` report?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm currently running 4.18.0 although the default ubuntu kernel for 18.04 doesn't work either.